# Doobie Query for Entities with Value Class Fields

Tags: scala, doobie

I am using **Doobie** to manage database persistence. I use *value class* fields in my entity `Foo` i.e.

```
    case class CreatedOn(value: LocalDateTime) extends AnyVal
    case class Resource(value: String) extends AnyVal
    case class Foo(id: Option[Int], resource: Resource, createdOn: CreatedOn)

    implicit fooRead: Read[Foo] = Read[(Option[Int], String, LocalDateTime)].map {
        case (oid, resource, createdOn) => Foo(oid, Resource(resource), CreatedOn(createdOn))
    }

    implicit fooWrite: Write[Foo] = Write[(Option[Int], String, LocalDateTime)].contramap {e => (e.oid, e.resource.value, e.createdOn.value}
```

Yet the compiler complains missing `Read[(Int, String, LocalDateTime)].map {...`
Any suggestions on how I can fix this? Is using value class a bad idea, to begin with, when comes to the entity? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doobie is able to read queries into `case class`es. If you imagine case classes as tuples and you imagine that you can flatten them then this is what Doobie does when you query things into a case class.

```
Foo(Some(1), Resource("test"), CreatedOn(time))
(Some(1), Tuple1("test"), Tuple1(time))
(Some(1), "test", time) // (Option[Int], String, LocalDateTime)
```

If your derivation fails you can check for which of these fields:

```
sql"".query[Int]
sql"".query[String]
sql"".query[LocalDateTime]
```

The line which fail compilation tells you the missing instance.

From my experience it is time instance. You have to import them separately, which you probably didn't import

```
doobie.implicits.javatime._
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and you are right, I missed the `javatime` import